# What is the max limit of response from bigquery REST API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using bigquery REST API for accessing bigquery data tables.
I want to display reports with pagination on web page. So let me know the max limit of the REST API response.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the limit to something large, you'll get only as many results as bigquery wants to give to you. I realize that this is a vague answer, but in general, you should set the maxResults flag to be the largest size you can handle, and then be prepared to receive a smaller amount than that if BigQuery decides to break it into smaller pages.